# How to run Biopython. I had installed it but it returns <no module found>?

Tags: bioinformatics, biopython

I had installed biopython but when I check for it. 
It returns no module found

```
pip3 install biopython
Requirement already satisfied: biopython in 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in 

python3
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52) 

import Bio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'
```

Comment: check `python3 -m pip --version` and `pip3 -V` to see if they match-up

Comment: still not working. It says no module ' No module named BIo'